# Why does my bank show me a picture whenever I try to login?

Tags: authentication

When I want to login into my bank account, I have to enter three things: username, id, and password. After I fill the username, and before I get to the id field, the bank shows me a picture - the same picture all the time (unless I make a mistake with the username, in which case I see a different picture). The website explains that this picture is somehow related to security, but does not explain how.

You can try this here: https://www.bankhadoar.co.il/#/Login 
Enter an arbitrary string in the first of the three fields, then click Tab to go to the next field, and you will see an image.

I have not seen such tricks in other websites.

QUESTION: how does this image help keep my account more secure?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a weirdly implemented variation of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26332/what-is-this-authentication-method-approach-called?rq=1

Comment: I think you've forgot to mention that it is not just always the same image if the name is correct but that it is actually an image you've explicitly chosen in your account setup. I agree with Jack that it is basically the same as asked in another question, i.e. knowledge based authentication. It does not matter if you picked a phrase (as in the other question) or an image for that. The advantages and disadvantages of this setup are also discussed in the other question, so I recommend to close this as duplicate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I actually did not choose the picture - it was chosen for me. But it seems the idea is the same.