# Name of security measure that shows user a personal word / phrase / drawing

Tags: phishing, defense, terminology

I remember a security measure I've seen on a few sites in the past against phishing, but I don't know what it's called. When the user logs in, or just inputs their username, the site shows some kind of secret word / phrase / drawing. That word / phrase / drawing is something the user always sees, so it's proof for them that they're talking to the real site.

I know that American Express uses it, and I've seen a few other sites in the past use it too.

Does anyone know what it's called?

Comment: I think it's simply a "shared secret".

Comment: I would refer to this answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26332/what-is-this-authentication-method-approach-called?rq=1):
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26332/what-is-this-authentication-method-approach-called?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this authentication method/approach called?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26332/what-is-this-authentication-method-approach-called)